# Why double is NaN after toggling bits?

Tags: c#, genetic-algorithm

I'm writing an genetic algorithm for finding coefficients having given X, Y points. The principle of operation is described on this page - https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-genetic-algorithms-including-example-code-e396e98d8bf3

I have problem, because sometimes after mutation or crossover my double value is NaN.

I've tried do this using byte[] and BitArray, but in both approaches I have the same result.

Converting double <-> BitArray:

```
public void ConvertByteArrayToCoefficients(BitArray array)
{
    Coefficients.Clear(); //Coefficients are stored in List<double>

    for (int i = 0; i < _degree + 1; i++)
    {
        var arr = array.ToByteArray();
        double value = BitConverter.ToDouble(array.ToByteArray(), i * sizeof(double));

        Coefficients.Add(value);
    }
}

public BitArray GetAllCoefficientsInBytes()
{
    BitArray bytes = new BitArray(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < Coefficients.Count; i++) //append is extension method
        bytes = bytes.Append(new BitArray(BitConverter.GetBytes(Coefficients[i])));

    return bytes;
}
```

Mutation:

```
public void Mutate(int percentageChance)
{
    BitArray bytes = GetAllCoefficientsInBytes();

    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
    {
        if (_randomProvider.Next(0, 100) < percentageChance)
        {
            if (bytes.Get(i))
                bytes[i] = false;
            else
                bytes[i] = true;
         }
    }

    ConvertByteArrayToCoefficients(bytes);
}
```

Crossover - method called for every two polynomial:

```
private void CrossoverSingle(Polynomial poly1, Polynomial poly2)
{
    int cutPosition = _randomProvider.Next(1, (_degreeOfPolynomial + 1) * sizeof(double) * 8);

    BitArray bytesOne = poly1.GetAllCoefficientsInBytes();
    BitArray bytesTwo = poly2.GetAllCoefficientsInBytes();

    for (int i = bytesOne.Length-1; i >= cutPosition; i--)
    {
        bool bitOne = bytesOne[i];
        bool bitTwo = bytesTwo[i];

        if (bitOne != bitTwo)
        {
            bytesOne[i] = bitTwo;
            bytesTwo[i] = bitOne;
        }
    }

    _crossoveredChildren.Add(new Polynomial(_randomProvider, _degreeOfPolynomial, bytesOne));
    _crossoveredChildren.Add(new Polynomial(_randomProvider, _degreeOfPolynomial, bytesTwo));
}
```

All code is on github: https://github.com/Makulak/CoefficientsFinder
Maybe You have any idea why it is happening?

Comment: Because you’re meddling with the bits and producing a bit pattern that means NaN. If you don’t want to get them you’ll have to make sure you don’t produce such patterns.

Comment: So, the quickest option is just simple ```do { .. }while(double.IsNan(value)``` when I change bits?

Comment: @JoeDoe No, that's a horrible way.

Comment: Are these integer, rational, or real coefficients? What does the `BitArray` value actually represent?

Comment: coeffitients are real. In BitArray I have all coefficients in binary (method GetAllCoefficientsInBytes())

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're using random bytes to generate IEEE-754 numbers. You should not do that because IEEE-754 defines the structure for these numbers and using random byte input won't give you random numbers because some bits represent things like the `is Not-a-Number` field, and NaN values are "viral" and invalidate other calculations.

To generate random `Double` numbers you should use `System.Random.NextDouble()`.

Comment: But in genetic algorithm I have to swap single bytes between two values, or mutate them (change randomly 0 <--> 1)

Comment: @JoeDoe But you can't do that though, this is because floating-point numbers don't have a trivial binary representation (the way that integers do). C# is not a language that's meant for editing raw bytes either. You need to rethink how your mutation algorithm will work (e.g. using values from parents to represent bounds on subsequent random numbers).